# Proving independence of random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables. I'm trying to prove that the following.

Suppose $P(X\in I_1,Y\in I_2)=P(X\in I_1)P(Y\in I_2)$ for all open interval $I_1,I_2$. Prove that $P(X\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty I_i,Y\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty J_i)=P(X\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty I_i)P(Y\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty J_i)$ where $I_i$ and $J_i$ are open intervals.

I'm not allowed to just say this follows from independence.

Comment: What is the question? The countable union of open sets remains an open set.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry

Comment: So basically you want to show that the interval-equality implies the open set equality.

Comment: Yes. It was originally implies sigma algebra but I know how to prove the complement condition. I don't know how to prove the infinite union condition.